# ros_readbagfile: command not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was following along the ROS tutorials since the beginning and I am having troubles on the ros_readbagfile command, because I am not able to running it:

I install the dependencies like asked in the beginning of the ros_readbagfile.py file:

```
sudo apt install python3-rosbag
```

And did the following steps how suggested in the tutorials:

```
# Download the file
  wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/master/useful_scripts/ros_readbagfile.py
# Make it executable
  chmod +x ros_readbagfile.py
# Ensure you have the ~/bin directory for personal binaries
  mkdir -p ~/bin
# Move this executable script into that directory as `ros_readbagfile`, so that it will
# be available as that command
  mv ros_readbagfile.py ~/bin/ros_readbagfile
# Re-source your ~/.bashrc file to ensure ~/bin is in your PATH, so you can use this
# new `ros_readbagfile` command you just installed
  . ~/.bashrc
```

But it is still not working and it appears "ros_readbagfile: command not found" when I run:

```
time ros_readbagfile demo.bag /obs1/gps/fix /diagnostics_agg | tee topics.yaml
```

Can someone help me how to figure it out why is not working?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371583/ros_readbagfile:-command-not-found/) by [goncaloski](https://answers.ros.org/users/69824/goncaloski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-02-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2021-02-11**:
I'd start by looking at your `PATH` environment variable and making sure that `~/bin/` is actually included. Can you run `echo $PATH`?

**Comment by [Super](https://answers.ros.org/users/70164/super/) on 2021-02-16**:
I had the same problem. If I run "~/bin$ echo $PATH" then i got:

/opt/ros/noetic/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

In the other hand, if I place myself on my bin folder and run "pwd" i got:

/home/username/bin

Actually I thing I do not understand quite good the problem, or why we have to ~/.bashrc if we already have created our bin folder.

Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2021-02-16**:
@Super please do not post answers that are actually answers. This is a Q&A site not a discussion forum. I've moved your answer to a question comment.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2021-02-16**:
@Super looking at the `PATH` variable you've posted, it's clear that the `~/bin` directory is *not* on your path. Without that directory being on your `PATH`, it will be impossible to execute the script. Likely the author of the instructions from OP's question was counting on the fact that if the `~/bin` directory exists, then on many Ubuntu/Debian systems it will automatically be added to the `PATH`. However, this would only happen upon re-running your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` (depending on those files' contents). This is why the instructions have you re-run the bashrc with `. ~/.bashrc`. Read more here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/402353/how-to-add-home-username-bin-to-path

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2021-08-27**:
Did you figure it out? I wrote `ros_readbagfile` and that tutorial.

**Comment by [Ruturaj](https://answers.ros.org/users/109220/ruturaj/) on 2022-06-29**:
I am facing the same problem, followed all steps in the tutorial , any solution to this? @eRCaGuy (Using Arch Linux, but am newbie to Linux.)

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2022-07-04**:
@Ruturaj, does this fix it for you? See my new answer: https://answers.ros.org/question/371583/ros_readbagfile-command-not-found/?answer=403354#post-id-403354

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe this is the first time you are creating the "~/bin" dir so try logging out of your user account and log in back, see if the command work now. If not, then try **replacing** the command:

```
mv ros_readbagfile.py ~/bin/ros_readbagfile
```

by:

```
ln -si "${PWD}/ros_readbagfile.py" ~/bin/ros_readbagfile
```

The command shoud work now after logging out and logging back in

---

Originally posted by [mentxlist](https://answers.ros.org/users/88114/mentxlist/) with karma: 21 on 2021-10-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am the author of this ROS wiki article: [Reading messages from a bag file](https://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/reading%20msgs%20from%20a%20bag%20file)

I'm also the author of the [`ros_readbag.py`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/ros_readbagfile.py) Python script, which is part of my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo.

To "install" the `ros_readbagfile.py` script, all we need to do is make it executable, name it `ros_readbagfile`, move it into the `~/bin` folder, and ensure that folder is in your `PATH` variable, which is a variable containing a list of folders your terminal will look in for executables whenever you type an executable name.

### How to add the `~/bin` directory to your `PATH` variable so that executables within it can be found

On Linux Ubuntu, the `~/bin` dir gets automatically added to your `PATH` variable if that dir exists! This happens because Ubuntu's default `~/.profile` file, which gets [`source`d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626515/4561887) whenever your Bash terminal starts up, contains these lines of code:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

So, if you have followed my installation instructions and they don't work, you are probably missing the above lines in your `~/.profile` file. So, create that file if it doesn't exist, then copy and paste that above code chunk into it. Then follow my instructions again.

You may need to re-source that file with this weird-looking command: `. ~/.profile`, OR re-source your bashrc file: `. ~/.bashrc`, OR log out and log back in. Now, view your `PATH` variable with `echo "$PATH"` and look to see that your `~/bin` dir is there. It will look like this, for instance, assuming your username is `gabriel`: `:/home/gabriel/bin:`.

That's it!

Does that work for you? Leave a comment below.

### Alternative fixes:

### Option 1: call the script by its full path instead

```
time ~/bin/ros_readbagfile demo.bag /obs1/gps/fix /diagnostics_agg | tee topics.yaml
```

### Option 2: manually run this in your terminal first:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

### Option 3: add this to your `~/.profile` file, OR to your `~/.bashrc` file

Option A:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

OR, even better: Option B:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Then [re-source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626515/4561887): `. ~/.bashrc` or log out and log back in.

### See also

1. My answer on [`source` (`.`) vs `export` (and also some file lock [`flock`] stuff at the end)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626515/4561887)

---

Originally posted by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) with karma: 171 on 2022-07-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1